# C++: Remotely execute a command under Windows machine

Tags: c++

I am esentially a Linux programmer and need to figure out remote command execution on Windows machine (C++). 
Checked some options like

> ```
> 1. psExec
> 2. rcmd
> 3. service control manager
> ```

Can anyone suggest which will be the best way for this purpose?
Some criteria:

> 1. Should work with all Windows OS (XP, Server etc).
> 2. Need to decide on basis of licensing issue, if it can be
>      incorporated in a commercial sofware
>      using C++.
> 3. Does Visual studio (VC++) provide any default interface for remote
>      command execution.

Answer (score 2):

It's not terribly hard.  You can login to a remote machine programmaticaly.  Once logged in, you can inject a service, start it up and then perform all the necessary work you need to perform.  Once done, uninstall the service and log out.

Answer (score 0):

You would normally have to connect to a service on that machine, or a daemon that the other machine is also connected to.

You then send the command to the service or the daemon.

There is no direct C++ call or operating system call for remote execution on another machine.

Answer (score 0):

psexec is a good choice.

As CashCow stated, windows (and visual studio) doesn't provide API for remote calls except DCOM. But in case of DCOM first you need to have registered COM object on this remote machine so then you can create it remotely and speak with it by RPC.

Comment: Can psexec be incorporated in a commercial sofware using C++. I need to run command on remote machine and get its output on local machine (through C++).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the AT command to schedule a task to run on a remote machine at a given time (i.e. in the very near future). Type `AT /?` on the command line for a description.